# Can I disable inbox alerts for new trading cards?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I like how my inbox icon lights up in green when I have new messages or new games from friends; but I'm not interested in trading cards, and it annoys me when after each gaming session I get a bunch and the inbox lights up.

Is there a way I can prevent the inbox alert from appearing for new trading cards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to disable those. Neither the Steam Client nor the Website or Enhanced Steam have this capability at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

No you cant not without disabling all notifications altogether.

Comment: You can't disable notifications.